# Conditioning of normal distributions

Tags: probability

I've been doing some self-studying during the summer and the textbook that I use only covers the bivariate case of conditioning of multivariate normal distributions.

**Problem:** The moment generating function of $(X,Y,Z)'$ is:$\psi(s,t,u)=\exp\{ \frac{s^2}{2}+t^2 + 2u^2-\frac{st}{2}+\frac{3su}{2} -\frac{tu}{2}\}$. Find the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $X+Y=0$ and $Y+Z=1$.

---

So far I've seen that the moment generating function can be written as $\psi(s,t,u)=\exp \{ \frac{1}{2} (s,t,u)\boldsymbol\Lambda(s,t,u)'\} $, where

$\boldsymbol\Lambda =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\
  -\frac{1}{2} & 2 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
  \frac{3}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 4\\
 \end{pmatrix}$
is the covariance matrix and the mean vector equals $\boldsymbol{\mu} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. My thoughts on the conditional part of the problem is to define new variables $U_1=X+Z$ and $U_2=Z+Y$ and thus the problem would be to find the distribution of $X$ when $\boldsymbol{U}=(0,1)'$. So the change of variables becomes: 
$$ \begin{cases}\widetilde{X}=X \\ 
U_1 = X+Z \\
U_2=Y+Z
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}X=\widetilde{X} \\ 
Z = U_1 - \widetilde{X} \\
Y=U_2 - U_1 + \widetilde{X}
\end{cases}$$
The absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix will end up equal to 1. So $f_{\widetilde{X},U_1,U_2}(\widetilde{x},u_1,u_2)=f_{X,Y,Z}(\widetilde{x},u_1-\widetilde{x},u_2-u_1+\widetilde{x})$ and I would have to integrate over $X$ to get the joint distribution for $\boldsymbol{U}=(U_1,U_2)'$. So then $f_{X|\boldsymbol{U}=(0,1)'}(x)=\frac{f_{X,U_1,U_2}(x,0,1)}{f_{U_1,U_2}(0,1)}$? Is this the correct way to work with conditioning in the general case, i.e. first use the transformation theorem of random variables? It seems like this leads to a lot of mechanical calculations, is there some easier way to do it?